# What is the proper placement for bathroom pendant sconces?

Tags: electrical, lighting, bathroom, light-fixture, bathroom-fixtures

Lighting experts recommend placing bathroom sconces ( sconces used on either side of a mirror above a vanity ) at eye level of the end user. Doing so reduces shadows. What about bathroom pendant lights? Should they by at eye level as well, or would that be a bad location as they might hit the end user in the face?

**Questions**

- How low should bathroom pendant lights hang?
- How far off the wall should bathroom pendant lights sit?

[image: Sketch of Design]